# jQuery : how to debug?

Tags: jquery

Recently i watched a tutorial from youtube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mwKq7_JlS8)

The boy is typing jQuery code and as soon as he presses enter key we can see the result intently. What tool is that?

Comment: If he says um or so one more time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)'s console in Firefox, which is available on Windows, too.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about intellisense, or debugging?

Firebug can help you debug, as intimated in the other answer.

If you are using a Visual Studio, then you should just be able to a breakpoint on the line to debug.

If you are referring to intellisense then the following will help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/07/hotfix-to-enable-vsdoc-js-intellisense-doc-files-is-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's TextMate or Firebug that Dmitri is using in his video. I think it's something custom the little dude has written. It's definitely running *inside* firebug though, you can see the titlebar it at the 4 minute mark. I can vaguely make out "somethingorother console 0.2" but I can't for the life of me google up anything about it. He's used a similar tool in [past talks](http://www.archive.org/details/DrupalconDc2009-Jquery?start=239.5) too

But, yeah, as a general rule the Firebug console will let you do this just as well, it's an awesome tool.